# Update a specific record from a SQL database by selecting the update button from a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, radgridview

I have a GridView that populates from a SQL database, each row in the gridview then has a update button in it. Now what i am trying to do is when i click on the update button of a specific row i want my database to set that specific row from active = true to active = false. How would i get my Linq Query to select that specific Data row in my database and update only that item?

Here is my asp.net code that creates my Button in the gridView

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateUpdateColumn">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateLink" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" OnClientClick="return confirm('You are about to update this Incident. \nAre you sure?')"><img src="../Images/icons/Trash.png" class="images" alt="Action" style="margin-left:5px"/></asp:LinkButton><br />Delete
</ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Here is my C# code that is supposed to update that specific record in my DB.

```
protected void grdIncidents_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
       Context db = new Context();

        var cmd = (from i in db.Incidents 
                   where i.IncidentID == //8
                   select i).FirstOrDefault();

        cmd.Active = false;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is you source code exactly as you typed it?  If so:

Right after `cmd.Active = false;` try `Context.Entry(cmd.Active).State = EntityState.Modified;`

That should tell the DbContext to update the values on that entity when you call "SaveChanges".  To make sure that your changes are actually being saved I would do the following:

```
var updateSuccessful = db.SaveChanges() > 0;
```

If `updateSuccessful` is equal to true, then the update worked.

Comment: var cmd = db.Incidents.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.IncidentID == /*your value*/);

This wont work, i need the gridview to know which incidentID i am refering to when i click the delete button.

So this piece of code should look something like this im guessing

where i.IncidentID == Current ID of record in the GridView

Comment: Right after cmd.Active = false; try Context.Entry(cmd.Active).State = EntityState.Modified doesnt work either VS doesnt know what Context.Entry is

Comment: what is the parent class of "Context"?  I was assuming that it's DbContext or some other entity framework context.  Also, in your question you don't specify the result that you're getting when your code runs.  Would you please add that information?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the sql command like this.
If you are using entity framework you should write `db.Entry(cmd).State = EntityState.Modified;` , after `cmd.Active = false;`
Also make sure that the Active column in your DB is actually of type bool.

```
protected void grdIncidents_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
   Context db = new Context();

    var cmd = db.Incidents.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.IncidentID == /*your value*/);

    cmd.Active = false;
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

checked if your fetched object is null or not. if it is null it can't be updated.

protected void grdIncidents_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Context db = new Context();

```
Incident cmd = (from i in db.Incidents 
       where i.IncidentID == //8
       select i).FirstOrDefault();

    if (cmd !=null)
    {
        cmd.Active = false;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    //Show some kind of message here like unable to update .
```

}